# maxlength not working for Input box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using below syntax ,

```
<span ng-repeat="item in basicProductInformation.productName">
        <input ng-show="currentLoggedInCompanyId == '566019bbb356de9283ded176'" ng-class="{errElementBorder: item.valueErr && !item.value}" class="form-control input-sm"  type="text"  ng-model="item.value" maxlength="500" ng-readonly="ValuesReadOnly"  style="height: 34px;">
        <input ng-hide="currentLoggedInCompanyId == '566019bbb356de9283ded176'" ng-class="{errElementBorder: item.valueErr && !item.value}" class="form-control input-sm"  type="text"  ng-model="item.value" maxlength="80" ng-readonly="ValuesReadOnly"  style="height: 34px;">
</span>
```

It is always taking maxlength of 80 after saving the changes nothing will be shown on UI for the first ng-show condition

For second input box (ng-hide) the text will be saved correctly and correctly shown on UI

Please suggest me if I did anything wrong?

Comment: try `ng-maxlength`

Comment: I created a fiddle using two inputs on the same ng-model and maxlength works fine. Maybe try to reproduce your issue on a fiddle and provide us the link.

Comment: I have tried the ng-maxlength,
<input ng-maxlength="{{ currentLoggedInCompanyId == '566019bbb356de9283ded176' ? 500 : 80 }}" ng-class="{errElementBorder: item.valueErr && !item.value}" class="form-control input-sm"  type="text"  ng-model="item.value" ng-readonly="ValuesReadOnly"  style="height: 34px;">
But it allows me more than 500 charecters

Comment: Is it inside a form element?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-maxlength. Here's the AngularJS documentation [ngMaxlength](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMaxlength).

And on your condition statement, try using '===' instead of '=='. There's a difference in comparing between the two because the '==' uses a type conversion. Read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons).

Comment: I have tried '===' in all condition but still it allows me to enter more than specified charecters in input box

Comment: Can you post a working fiddle regarding your problem? P.S. my advice is to always use '===' on your comparison.